# Jmeter video call scenario

Tags: jmeter

I need to achieve the below scenario using jmeter how can i do it please help

1. Login in to site with general user and schedule a appointment with doctor.
2. Login with doctor and accept appointment and video call the user at that time.
3. The user need to lift the video call and keep the session open for one min
4. Logout both the sessions.

please help how to achieve the above.

Comment: Have you referred this article? https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-http-live-media-streaming-hls-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WebDriver sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) as a core element and build your scenario with it.
Here's the basic [tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/).